# How to invoke [self new] in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview

Here is an `UIView` extension written in ObjectiveC to easily create view for using Auto-layout:

```
+(id)autolayoutView
{
    UIView *view = [self new];
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    return view;
}
```

it invokes `[self new]` so any subclass of UIView can use this method. How can I achieve this in Swift?

Comment: write it as a UIView category in objC and bridge it to swift? swift isn't really meant to be that dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, this appears to be the solution. The type must have a `required` initializer with the correct parameter list (in this case no parameters).

```
class SubView: UIView {
    override required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    class func autolayoutView() -> UIView {
        var view = self()
        view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Compared to the ObjC way, this is pretty clunky. I really wish Swift had been a fully dynamic language like ObjC, just with a cleaner syntax. Something like F-Script or nu.

Comment: Yes, `self()` does work. But you don't need to do subclass. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Gregory Higley, i think the solution is here:

```
extension UIView{
    class func autolayoutView() -> UIView {
        var view = self()
        view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        return view
    }
}
```

**Update for Swift2.1:**

```
extension UIView{
    class func autolayoutView() -> UIView {
        let view = self.init()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed the part where you said "UIView extension".

Answer (score 1):

Though both Carrl and Gregory Higley are right with there solutions, including thr remark about the fact that self() needs to use a required init i wanted to post a more general example:

```
class Human {
    var gender = String()
    required init() {
        self.gender = "any"
    }
    class func newHuman() -> Human {
        return self()
    }
}

class Man : Human {
    required init() {
        super.init()
        self.gender = "male"
    }
}

var someMan = Man.newHuman()
println(someMan.gender) // male
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same code I used in my playground experiment, except I used the less imaginative `Foo` and `Bar`.